# Custom webview in cordova app

Tags: java, android, cordova, webview, ionic-framework

I am new to android development and just started working on a web app using cordova, ionic framework and angular. I have completed the basic features of the app and found that the transitions between views in the app are a bit slow 
I found this article to improve them here:
https://github.com/ajoslin/angular-mobile-nav/wiki/PhoneGap,-improving-performance

I have never coded in java and so I am stuck.

I tried doing the following

went to the cordovawebview.java in the path  `myapp\platforms\android\CordovaLib\src\org\apache\cordova` and added the import statements missing in the file (except for the "import org.apache.cordova.CordovaWebView")
 which were using in the article and copy-pasted the myWebview class.

Then I went to the StarterApp.java,  below path

```
\myapp\platforms\android\src\com\ionicframework\starter
```

and modified it to

```
public class StarterApp extends CordovaActivity 
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        CordovaWebView webView = new MyWebView(MyActivity.this);
    super.init(webView, new CordovaWebViewClient(this, webView), new     CordovaChromeClient(this, webView));
        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());
         //super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html")
    }
}
```

But when I run the cordova build command I am getting a error. Could someone tell me, what I am missing?

Comment: can you please provide your log cat output?

Answer (score 0):

This looks incorrect to me:

```
CordovaWebView webView = new MyWebView(MyActivity.this);
```

1. Have you written code for `MyWebView`?
2. `MyActivity` doesn't seem to exist. You can just use `this`.